# Can we set particular time by using device owner application

Tags: android

Can we set time by using device owner application.when i look to the DevicePolicyManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html
i found **EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCAL_TIME**, My query by using this constant can we set time according to the device owner specifications like may 19,2013 15:20 or based on the company server time without rooting the device.

And If I'm correct, it is possible to set by using Setting.Global.AUTO_TIME which use network (NITZ) for setting time.If it is **COSU** device which have no network access.If this is the case, is it possible to set the time with Android EMM device owner.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set the device time from app, although in your case you can set a constant time/date in your class, where you can set time/date according to you need after that send it your server.

Comment: Means we can't set time of the device by device-owner also..?

Comment: What do you mean "set a time"? You want to change the time of the device or just display it in your app? If you want to get the user date and time format preferences you should use the "Locale"

Comment: Then what is the use of **EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCAL_TIME**..?

Comment: Hi Eselfar..i need to change the time of the device

Comment: From android app this is not possible,

Comment: Android EMM Developers: i saw it is possible 
https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devicesAlways required
EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME
Required if a DPC isn’t already installed on the device

EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION
EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM
Recommended if the device isn’t already connected to Wi-Fi

EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID
EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD
Optional

EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCALE
EXTRA_PROVISIONING_TIME_ZONE
EXTRA_PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCAL_TIME

Comment: this are the properties which we can set by using Android EMM applications

Comment: if I'm not wrong, I understood like we can set time in Android EMM Application with help of device owner. like Time, Wi-Fi configuration, setting User Restriction and COSU Mode from android 6 and above versions.